# Problema ao tentar usar valores de um JSON - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Bem tenho o seguinte código em javascript dentro de uma função chamada *query()* que recebe o valor *index* de um input:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (!request) {
    alert('Que pena :( a requisição não pode ser feita');
}else{

    request.onreadystatechange = resposta;
    request.open('GET', 'query.php?busca='+index);
    request.send();
}


function resposta() {
    if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log(request.response);

            document.getElementById('nome').innerHTML = request.response;
            document.getElementById('tamanho').innerHTML = request.response;

            resp = request.response;
            console.log(resp);
            return resp;

        } else {
            return 'Problema na requisição';
        }
    }
}
```

A função recebe um JSON como esse de um código PHP:

> {"nome":"peixe","tamanho":"30"}

Mas quando altero a variável **resp** para **resp.nome** ou **resp.tamanho** o valor da variável se torna undefined.

Comment: Essa função é chamada assincronamente logo o `return` não tem sentido. Mas aproveite e coloque também o código onde está a tentar mudar o valor de  `resp.nome`

Comment: Não estou tentando mudar o valor, somente exibi-lo. Quando uso `console.log(resp)` o valor retornado é um JSON mas quando uso `console.log(resp.nome)` o valor retornado é undefined. E obrigado pelo aviso sobre os returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa converter o retorno do Ajax em objeto JSON. No momento ele apenas é uma *string*. Use o método `JSON.parse()`. Troque:

```
resp = request.response;
```

Por:

```
resp = JSON.parse(request.response);
```

> Retire também o `return resp;` desnecessário.

[**Documentação do método.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)